# AWS Cognito Tokens Invalid after Sign in with Apple

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

After a "successful" federated Sign in with Apple I get the message on the console that the tokens are not valid. How can I refresh them?

```
  AWSMobileClient.default().federatedSignIn(providerName: IdentityProvider.apple.rawValue, token: token) { (userState, error)  in
        if let error = error {
            print("Federated Sign In failed: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }else{
            print("federatedSignIn successful: \(userState)")
        }
    }
```

On the console I get this even listener. Right after login , it gets signed out, so the user can't make any API calls

> AWSMobileClient Event listener - signedIn

> AWSMobileClient Event listener - signedOutFederatedTokensInvalid

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this?